# Firebase Rules Flat structure for stores, user, products relationship

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rules, nosql

i try to build a firebase Datastructure.
i come from a SQL world and have Problems understanding noSQL Datastructur.

i would like to have a Datastructure for Stores.
Each Store has some Datafields like Storename, Address and so on.
A Store should also have a Users Object storing all the Users that work in this Store and are able to add new Products and modify them.
There is also a Dataobject that stores the Products and the Products should
have also a relation to the users(stores).
Can someone give me a hint how to build this as flat as possible?

My data structure right now:

```
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
       ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
       ".read": "auth !== null && auth.provider === 'password'"
      }
     },
    "products": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
        ".read": true
       }
     },
    "stores": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
        ".read": true
      }
    }
   }
```

Thanks

Comment: A NoSQL data structure does not just depend on the entities you want to store, but also on the way you want to *use* the data.

Comment: Take a look at: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html

Comment: You've included [Firebase Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) in your question which are independent of your Firebase Structure. However, they do provide control over your structure. Please remove those from the question and include the structure you've tried so far. I would suggest setting your rules to .read and .write to true for all nodes while you are working to understand NoSQL. Also, there are no objects in Firebase, the objects would exist in your code which is backed by a JSON structure in Firebase.